# My img tag dont show i jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm using Jquery to get a special image in the resource folder in a dynamic web project. Without the script i'm trying to just look how it should look but my tag don't work?

```
$("#test").html('<h:graphicImage library="images" name="TCGBottomHot.png" />');
$("#test2").html('<img alt="ingen bild" src="images/TCGBottomHot.png" />');
```

Comment: please mention all relevant code

Comment: Your first example won't work as `<h:graphicImage>` is a JSF tag which needs to be interpreted by the server before sending the HTML to the client. The second one should work fine though, assuming the image path is correct

Comment: Update your code src="~/images/TCGBottomHot.png" 
hope it works.